# print multiple lines using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, newline

I'm creating a simple client-server to use with my Raspberry Pi.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to send "ACKTEMP" for example to the Server using my Client. The servers then calls the serial port (which is my STM32 Nucleo Board btw) with this message I get the temperature back using the serial communication and after that it sends it back to the Client.

My question is, the Nucleo board returns some strings like (TEMP: xx) this works fine until I start sending multiple strings back at once ex. if I send ACKTEMP and want to receive (TEMP: xx ) and "Temperature OK", doing this I only get the first line which is (TEMP: xx ).

So it seems that somewhere in my code I need to change something so it prints out all the lines instead of just one and then stop. Please don't get angry at me if my programming isn't that great I'm a student and trying to understand everything.

```
    public class Client {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String sentence;
        String messageFromServer;
        while(true)
        {
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.135", 6789)) {
            PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
            outToServer.println(sentence + '\n');
            messageFromServer = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + messageFromServer);
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        }
    }

}

    public class Server {
        private static SerialPort serialPort;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
         serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0");


         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            try{
             //opening port
            serialPort.openPort();

            serialPort.setParams(
                    SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            //Write string to port
            serialPort.writeString(clientSentence + "\n");

            System.out.println("String wrote to port, waiting for response.."); 

            try {
                     Thread.sleep(10);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

            String buffer = serialPort.readString();
            outToClient.println(buffer + '\n');

            serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port

            }
            catch(SerialPortException ex){
            System.out.println("Error writing data to port: " + ex);
            } 
         }
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to kinda solve this problem. But if someone has a better solution it is very welcome!

What I did is for every string I want a new line, I put a "~" sign in front of the string in my Nucleo STM32 program.

```
       String strArray[] = messageFromServer.split("~");

       System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + strArray[0]);

       for(int i = 1; i < strArray.length; ++i)
       {
           if(messageFromServer.indexOf('~') >= 0)
           {
               System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + strArray[i]);
           }
       }
```